# get specific column from list in mvc using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and trying to build put a simple web application.

**I have a Class - ListItems**

```
public class ListItems
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**From controller** -

I am using function to populate values of dropdownlist .Data is populated to ListItems

```
 List<ListItems> Lst= new List<ListItems>();

        string query = @"SELECT DISTINCT A.[COLA],A.[COLB],[COLC] FROM tableA ";
```

**getting to Dataset ds**

```
ListItems item;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                item = new ListItems();
item.Value = DBBase.ConvertToString(row["COLA"], string.Empty);           
item.Display = DBBase.ConvertToString(row["COLB"], string.Empty);
item.Area = DBBase.ConvertToString(row["COLC"], string.Empty);
                    statusList.Add(item);
            }
```

**In View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.COLA, new SelectList(Model.VenueList, "Value", "Display","Area"), "- Please select a Value-", new { id = "lstA" })
```

Now, I need to get value of 'Area' Column of dropdownlist 'lstA' in javascript
on button click

**In javascript**

```
function AB(){

$('#lstVenue :selected').val(); // this gives selected value
}
```

> How to get value of column 'Area' ?

Comment: Javascript can only get you a) whatever you rendered into resulting html or b) whatever you want via an ajax call. For your use case option b looks like an overkill. So, does the value of column `Area` end up in your rendered html or not?

Comment: You would need to handle the `change()` event of the dropdownlist and call a server method to get the value of `Area` based on the selected value (or you could assign your list to a javascript variable and get it from there)

Comment: I have added column "Area" to dropdownlist in View -- @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.COLA, new SelectList(Model.VenueList, "Value", "Display","Area"), "- Please select a Value-", new { id = "lstA" }) .. Wouldn't that be rendered in html?

Comment: @user_rhee, No, it will not be rendered. `DropDownListFor()` renders options with a value attribute and a display text only (the values of your `Value` and `Display` properties. Adding `"Area" is ignored.

Comment: Ok .. can you add some light on where you have mentioned, - handle the change() event of the dropdownlist and call a server method to get the value of Area based on the selected value. Pleease help in detail pls

Comment: What do you need the value for? What do you do with it?

Comment: i am binding a value to 'Area' column  from db query which  has values 1 or 0 based on a condition. Now in my Javascript function i need to check if the value of Area = 0 , then open new mode view else open Edit mode view.

Comment: hi any help.. pls.. stuck like anything here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a dropdown list cannot bind 3 values, you have to set `Value` and `Area` to values of options with a unique character (I used '#' as an example) like this:

```
// Make sure '#' doesn't appear on "Value" nor "Area" 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.COLA, new SelectList(Model.VenueList.Select(v => new { Display = v.Display, Value = string.Concat(v.Value, "#", v.Area) }), "Value", "Display"), "- Please select a Value-", new { id = "lstA" })
```

Then, you can get both "Value" and "Area" with JavaScript(jQuery) like this:

```
var selected = $('#lstA :selected').val();
var splited = selected.split("#");
var value = splited[0];
var area = splited[1];
if (area == "0"){
    // Do something
}
```